# Custom text on virtual portal login portlet

Tags: websphere-portal

I changed the text "Log in with your Portal account" by downloading the PA_Login_Portlet_App, modifying the loginportlet_en.properties file, exporting to an ear and updating the app in the console.
This worked.
However, the text is unchanged on my virtual portal.
Is there a way to change both?
Does the virtual portal derive the text from a separate properties file?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the ear was updating the login portlet properly. I had a DNS issue and was looking at the wrong environment and thought the virtual portal was unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual Portal uses a separate set of Content Tree. The Login page which is there in Virtual portal might be using the default Login portlet of IBM. You need to access the Administration page of Virtual portal and change the login portlets in Login Page.

Comment: The problem turned out to be pilot failure. You are correct though, once I fix the keyboard-to-chair issue, both login portlets were identical.